# vim how to create a debug message fast

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using ruby on rails but that does not matter much for this question. Let's say that i have a statement like this

```
error = 'this is an error message'
```

I have noticed that I end up doing this a lot

```
error = 'this is an error message'
puts "error = #{error.inspect}"
```

I am sure a macro can be written which would take the work on the left hand side of left most = and then create another line along with template shown above.

I am using mvim on mac. Any pointer in terms of where I should start to look for developing what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Try snipmate:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540

Answer (score 3):

I recorded a simple macro that does your sample. To record a macro type <kbd>q</kbd> followed by what register you want the macro to be put in (convention calls for <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>). To play the macro type <kbd>@</kbd> then the macro register. You can view this at `:help recording`

To write the macro, use the following commands (and here is how is should look in the register)

```
^yEoputs "error = #{^Op.inspect}"^[
```

`^` moves to the first non whitespace character of the line

`yE` yanks to the end of the space separated word.

`o` Puts you in insert mode on the next line

`puts "error = #{` is the text that you type out

`^O` is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (capital letter o) - this allows the next, and only the  next command to be run in command mode, which is...

`p` Puts the yanked word, after this command is run you're still in insert mode

`.inspect}"` is the text that you type and finally...

`^[` is <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
nnoremap µ :s/^\s*\(\k\+\)\s*=.*/&\rputs "\1 = #{\1.inspect}"/<cr>
```

`:s` presents the advantage of doing the job plus matching the assigned variable if any. Doing the same thing with classical commands like `yw`, `p`, etc would be more cumbersome.

If the template become more complex, we can rely on template-file expanders as long as they easily permit to call viml function like `matchstr()`. Of course, in that case I would use [mu-template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate) with the following template-file:

```
VimL:" $Id: {rtp}/template/ruby/inspect.template
VimL: let s:value_start  = '¡'
VimL: let s:value_end    = '¡'
VimL: let s:reindent     = 1
VimL: let s:marker_open  = '<+'
VimL: let s:marker_close = '+>'
VimL: let s:varname = matchstr(getline(line('.')-1), '^\s*\zs\k\+\ze\s*=')
VimL: if empty(s:varname) |throw "the previous line don't assign any variable" |endif
puts "¡s:varname¡ = #{¡s:varname¡.inspect}"<++>
VimL:"vim: encoding=utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing these on the fly, a snipmate snippet could look like this:

```
${1:error} = '${2:error message here}'
puts "error = #{$1.inspect}"
```

If, on the other hand you're just wanting to output pre-existing variables for debugging purposes. Nick-Canzoneri's macro may be more useful.